# Is that possible,pass an array of colors in uiimageview border's color

Tags: ios

Here is my code,

```
cell.imagename.image=[ColorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your code that `imagename` is a `UIImageView`. If so, I think you are looking for this code. `objectAtIndex:` will return an `id`, so you will need to cast it to a `UIColor` in order to use the `.CGColor` property.

```
UIColor *borderColor = (UIColor *)[ColorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
cell.imagename.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: Tried but,property not found on object of type 'id' this error was shown

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If the cast isn't needed, then what property wasn't found and what object is of type `id`?

Comment: The cast isn't need in the updated code in your question. A cast (or change to use the getter method) was needed in the answer's original code (and the OP's code).

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, class of objects in NSArray will be `id` (AnyObject in Swift, mean can be any kind of object), then if an object is `id`. Property  CGColor will not found on object of type `id`. So first get the object from NSArray and cast it to `UIColor`, then it will have the property `CGColor`. You can work with the code from @keithbhunter Answer.

Comment: Or change the property syntax to calling the getter method. This won't require a cast.